# RabbitMQ badmatch error

Tags: rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ instance to handle messages. I noticed that because of some reason Rabbit stopped sending messages to consumers, which ends up at very low disk space in the system, because of constantly growing queue.

I have been able to find following information in rabbit's log file:

```
** Reason for termination == 
** {{badmatch,{error,enospc}},
    [{rabbit_msg_store,terminate,2,
                       [{file,"src/rabbit_msg_store.erl"},{line,975}]},
     {gen_server2,terminate,3,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1146}]},
     {proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,250}]}]}
** In 'terminate' callback with reason ==
** {{badmatch,{error,enospc}},
    [{rabbit_msg_store,write_message,3,
                       [{file,"src/rabbit_msg_store.erl"},{line,1160}]},
     {rabbit_msg_store,handle_cast,2,
                       [{file,"src/rabbit_msg_store.erl"},{line,881}]},
     {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1049}]},
     {proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,250}]}]}
```

Have any of you guys ever had such a problem? Any help or information what rabbit try to tell me would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`** {{badmatch,{error,enospc}},` is an Erlang Error:

> enospc
>       There is a no space left on the device.

Basically you just have to free the space!

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you.